# more than one defaction in the body?

Tags: krl

All, can I run more than one defaction in the body of the rule? or can I only run one?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Contact list not, swipe again please. But seriously, could you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define as many actions in the `pre` block of a rule as you want. You can have as many actions in the action block of a rule as you want (just enclose the action block in curly braces). For example,

```
rule first_rule {
  select when pageview ".*" setting ()
  pre {
    notify_one = defaction() { notify("notify_one", "First defaction"); };
    notify_two = defaction() { notify("notify_two", "Second defaction"); };
  }
  {
    notify_one();
    notify_two();
  }
}
```

So I think the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little confusing, but I'll give it a run.

Running actions defined with `defaction` is just like running system defined actions.

If you want to run more then one action in a rule, you need to wrap them in {} like so:

```
rule foo {
  select when pageview ".*"
  {
    notify("cheese", "brie");
    notify("apple", "golden delicious");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that a defaction has an implicit, optional 'pre' section, followed by the action(s). To include multiple actions you do need {} as Sam says.

```
act1 = defaction() {
  {
    notify("Defaction Demo", "<ul id='demo_id'></ul>");
    append("#demo-id", "<li>cheese: brie</li>");
    append("#demo-id", "<li>apple: golden delicious</li>");
  }
};
```

That works out to `defaction() { { ... } };` but the extra curly braces are required if you want more than one action in a defaction.

See also http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Defaction

Comment: http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Defaction is incomplete, can we get better documentation?